# RNN sequence length and cell size

Tags: tensorflow, rnn, sequence

I am trying to build a RNN model to classify time series.
My time series data consist of numbers with length 200.

I am using tensorflow, and when i create the placeholder for the data it is like this:

```
inputs = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 200, 1], name='inputs')
```

200 is the sequence length and 1 is the features, which in my case is 1 feature per time step.

And when i create the RNN using GRU cell i use this:

```
tf.contrib.rnn.GRUCell(400)
```

I use 400 as cell size of GRU cell because as far as i know the internal state + the inputs will be used as the new input for the next GRU cell, so i suppose the cell must be input length x 2.

Is this logic of mine correct?
Is the initialization of inputs correct?

BATCH SIZE = None

SEQUENCE LENGTH = 200

FEATURES = 1

And is the GRU cell parameters correct?

CELL SIZE = 2 x SEQUENCE LENGTH?

Or have i understood it incorrectly?

Comment: Would you share your code? It is hard to see your situation. Also please put reference that cell size should be sequence length double.